# Why isn't this simple broadcast receiver working?

Tags: java, android

I have two apps each with an accessibility service. The accessibility service of one app sends a broadcast and the accessibility service of the other app receives it.

Here is the service sending the broadcast:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.corps.mypackage");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //this is needed if broadcast not being sent from activity
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And here is the service that receives the broadcast:

```
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.corps.mypackage");
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //Do some things
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
```

The broadcast is not being received. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#context-registered-receivers):

> Context-registered receivers receive broadcasts as long as their registering context is valid. For example, if you register within an Activity context, you receive broadcasts as long as the activity is not destroyed. If you register with the Application context, you receive broadcasts as long as the app is running.

Your receiving app's context is likely not valid. Consider using a [manifest-declared receiver](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#manifest-declared-receivers) instead.

Comment: But I'm 100% sure it's valid since the accessibility service is turned on. Perhaps I should add something to the broadcast, like data or extras?

Comment: Hey so I tried adding the receiver to the manifest and created a custom class for the receiver as usual but the broadcast is still not getting received!